# Custom pane data not retained on back button

Tags: commerce

I have created a custom checkout pane in the checkout form. The panes order is: checkout->custom_pane->review->complete

When I click 'continue to next step' on custom pane, it goes to review pane and I see all the custom pane data. However when I click the 'Go back' on review pane, it's not retaining the data on custom pane. I see only blank fields on custom pane.

Appreciate any help. I am new to DrupalCommerce.